# JS : Using a setTimeout inside a setInterval, the setTimeout has no effect

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to make random images move upwards then return to their original position.

```
<script>

var looper = setInterval(animateAll, 2000, myArray);
function animateAll(myArray) {

    // Gets a random image ID
    var randomId = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)]; 

    // Make that random icon bounce
    bounce(randomId) ;
}

function bounce(randomId) {
    var icon = document.getElementById(randomId)

    var top = icon.offsetTop;

    setTimeout ( icon.style.top = top-20 + "px", 500) ;
    setTimeout ( icon.style.top = top + "px", 500) ;
}
</script>
```

Both `setTimeout` lines work fine. With only one line, well the images will move without returning to their original position. With both lines, images don't move at all, probably because there's no delay between each.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: dont you need to be passing a function to the first argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're executing the code in your `setTimeout` calls immediately.  You're effectively saying "execute the result of setting the `icon.style.top = whatever` in 500 milliseconds" ... which does nothing.

Try this instead:

```
icon.style.top = top-20 + "px";
setTimeout ( function() { icon.style.top = top + "px"; }, 500) ;
```

... and I just blew 15 minutes on this, lol:

```
var steps = 7;
var increment = (Math.PI) / steps;
var bounceHeight = 20;

function doStep(icon, start, major, minor, height) {
    if (minor == steps) {
        major--;
        height /= 2;
        minor = 0;
        icon.style.top = start;
    }
    if (major < 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (minor < steps) {
        pos = Math.sin((minor + 1) * increment);
        icon.style.top = (start - height * pos) + "px";
        setTimeout( function() { doStep(icon, start, major, minor + 1, height); }, 500/steps );
    }
}

function bounce(randomId) {
    var icon = document.getElementById(randomId)

    var top = icon.offsetTop;
    setTimeout ( function() { doStep(icon, top, 3, 0, bounceHeight); }, 500/steps ) ;
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @tempse try the new version :)

Comment: ... except it has issues if left running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the image up immediately when you call bounce and then returning it to the original position after a timeout?

```
function bounce(randomId) {
    var icon = document.getElementById(randomId)

    var top = icon.offsetTop;

    icon.style.top = top-20 + "px";
    setTimeout ( icon.style.top = top + "px", 500) ;
}
```