# JS - several setTimeout in a row?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Just a followup to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125419/js-using-a-settimeout-inside-a-setinterval-the-settimeout-has-no-effect),

I'm making a picture move up and down, with the following code :

```
icon.style.top = top-50 + "px";
setTimeout ( function() { icon.style.top = top + "px"; }, 200) ;
```

Now i'd like to implement more intermediate positions. The idea is to induce a translation effect. I tried to stack setTimeout lines, but didn't work.

I'm reading some stuff about clearTimeout right now, but probably your help will make it work just better. Thanks !

Comment: Setting several timeouts in a row is perfectly valid: each will be executed when its own delay is up. But for an animation you probably want to use a named function that sets a timeout to call itself to queue up the next frame of the animation.

Comment: ^ https://jsfiddle.net/0m57n38k/2/

Comment: As @nnnnnn said, you indeed should use a named function that trigger the animation at the end of execution. JQuery animations are a good example.

Comment: Thanks adaneo, that works just fine, i just didn't understant setTimeout fully yet

Answer (score 2):

You can "stack" the setTimeout calls if you want. Just remember that they are called *immediately* and only take action after the given millisecond argument.

So if I want three callbacks to take place within 200 milliseconds of each other, using 200 as the argument is incorrect. The first one should be 200, and then 400, and then 600 - or to break it out `i * 200` where `i` is the iterator.

```
var offsets = [-50,50,0,-100,100,0];   //some set of pixel offsets
var timing = 200;   //the 200 millisecond argument
for(var i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++){   //loop through offsets with i
    (function(i){ //close over the i value to ensure the value is saved
    setTimeout( function() {   //setup the timeout
        icon.style.top = (top+offsets[i]) + "px";   //change the style offset
    }, timing*i);   //multiply the 200 milliseconds by loop counter
    })(i)   //close over the i value
}
```

Comment: Works ok most of the time but you should not trigger them all at the same time. It's always better to chain the calls do because there is no guarantee that a call will be made on the time you specified. A better approach is to calculate the tween based on the initial time to account for those delays. That is, you schedule a timeout for 200 ms, but it only gets triggered after 300, you can set the next timeout to 100 ms to prevent the  delays from accumulating and adjusting the current css property  (offset in on this case) taking the delay into account

Comment: @JuanMendes - This is just explaining how to "stack" the timeouts in the OP's words. Note that the question was not "how do I schedule callbacks to fire at specific times" which would require a global interval and a scheduler to fire the callbacks. It is far more efficient and accurate to use an interval with a scheduler than to chain callbacks or even fire a "stack" of callbacks as shown here. But again, that wasn't really the question.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, it answers the question. I'm just pointing out it's a bad idea and that there's a better way. And I hope that by "use an interval with a scheduler" doesn't mean setInterval since it is the worst you could possibly do, the calls can queue up of the system bogs down and they would all fire at once. Sometimes you have to answer past the question when it looks like the OP intended to do something that has a lot of drawbacks.